# SQL asking to show column that has multiply by 1.2

Tags: mysql

we got this activity question that say's:

"Work with the values in the columns in table. Show ProductName, Price, Price that has multiply by 1.2 as CustomerPays as additional column (Clue 3 columns will be shown in your table)."

And i kinda getting a hard time understanding on what command should I use, Can someone help me ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZNw.png)

Comment: That question isn't good English. What is "that has multiply by 1.2" supposed to mean.

Comment: You need to understand what the question is asking you - Instead of Select * from orderinfo, you need to select the individual columns (ProductName, Price, Price ) and then multiply the second Price column by *1.2 and alias it as CustomerPays

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```sql
SELECT ProductName, Price, 1.2*Price AS CustomerPays
FROM yourTable;
```